# Chartist.js chart artifact

Tags: javascript, charts, chartist.js

What could be the cause to this artifact? I have moved my code from my codepen https://codepen.io/mads10000/pen/vaBdBd

```
<div class="chartsContainer">
  <div class="slaChart">
  </div>
</div>
```

to my HTML boilerplate 
[Github - Commit with chart that has an artifact](https://github.com/m-schou/chartcoal/commit/f0ae09d9be9bb044df61cc2a0e183347c03caca8)

It should not have these black spots as seen on image. It looks right on my codepen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, showLine: false, fixed it.

```
var lineChart = new Chartist.Line('.slaChart', {
    labels: ['January', '', 'February', '', 'March'],
    series: [
        // [0, 5, 8, 10, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4],
        [0, 50, 35, 70, 50, 90],
        [0 , 45, 25, 55, 35, 70]
    ]
}, {
    low: 0,
    high: 100,
    showArea: true,
    showLine: false, <-------- showLine false fixed it
    showPoint: false,
    fullWidth: true,
    plugins: [
        // Chartist.plugins.lineSelector()
    ],
    axisY: {
        onlyInteger: true,
        offset: 20
    },
    axisX: { showGrid: false }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the CSS fill property. Something on your page might have set the default fill to be black. For a line path the fill doesn't make sense to clear it you just need to reset the fill to none.

```
.ct-line {
  fill: none
}
```